# file conversion layers to volume

Tags: 3d, webgl, dicom

in the field of radiology there are many ways to scan a part or even the whole body. i need to convert many medical dicom-files (> 100 layers) to one volume file to transfer a 3d-volume instead of 2d-data.
one format is the **.nrrd** format used here:

[xtk](http://demos.goxtk.com/daniels_brain/)

i know there is [slicer](http://www.slicer.org/) but is there another way to convert the files? did anybody come across this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mri_convert` from the freesurfer package.

http://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/

Then, just do

```
mri_convert *.dcm output.mgz
```

and you get .MGZ format which XTK can read :)